# Create file on Google Drive App Folder Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I Was try to upload file to google drive app folder, but i am stuck.
I was try to use this code for example but i am getting errors:

```
    File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("config.json");
fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/config.json");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

And the errors:

[image]

Why I am getting this errors?

Comment: Have you properly imported `com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;` to your class file? Like this [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert) by Google.